# Inherith the variables from other template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to inherith the variable from previous template to current one.

Here is my xsl, wondering if there is some thing wrong:

```
<xsl:template match="child1">
    <xsl:variable name="props-value">
        <xsl:value-of select="VALUE1"/>
    </xsl:variable>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute[matches(.,'=@')]">
        <xsl:with-param name="props-value" select="$props-value" /> 
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>  
<xsl:template match="attribute[matches(.,'=@')]">
<xsl:param name="props-value"/>
<xsl:copy>  
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:if test="$props_value = 'VALUE1'">
        Value is true
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected output: Value is true.

Comment: any suggestions please...

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with your XSLT:

1. In the variable in the first template, you've selected `"VALUE1"` as the value. This matches `<VALUE1>` *elements*. I believe you want to select `" 'VALUE1' "` (a string with the value 'VALUE1')
2. In your test in the second template, you've written `$props_value` with an underscore, whereas the parameter is called `props-value` with a hyphen.

Here's a corrected version of your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="child1">
    <xsl:variable name="props-value">
      <xsl:value-of select=" 'VALUE1' "/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute">
      <xsl:with-param name="props-value" select="$props-value" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="attribute">
    <xsl:param name="props-value"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:if test="$props-value = 'VALUE1'">
        Value is true
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following input XML:

```
<child1>
  <attribute/>
</child1>
```

it produces this output XML:

```
<attribute>
            Value is true
          </attribute>
```